# Minimizing a conditional function with parameters

Tags: mathematical-optimization, version-10

Is there a way to find the minimum of a piecewise functions with parameters?

Here is a simple example:

```
Minimize[{If[x > 0, 3 x, x^2 - x - 4]}, x]
```

works fine, but

```
Minimize[{If[x > 0, 3 x, x^2 - x - a], -2 < a < 2}, x]
```

doesn't work at all.

Is there some way to make it work? Or can anyone explain why is not working or suggest other methods to get the minimum?

#### Edit 1

The answer I would like to get is something like:

> ```
> If[a < 0, 0, -a]
> ```

#### Edit 2

When I try

```
Minimize[{If[x > 0, 3 x, x^2 - x - a], -2 < a < 2}, x]
```

I get as output:

> ```
> Minimize[{If[x > 0, 3 x, x^2 - x - a], -2 < a < 2}, x]
> ```

I'm using  V10.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (March 24, 2015)"

Comment: It's not clear to me what you aim at. I would suggest to use `Minimize[{If[x > 0, 3 x, x^2 - x - a], -2 < a < 2}, {x, a}]` instead. But since Mathematica tells me that there is no minimum, I am in doubt that this is what you are looking for...

Comment: It works for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/oMzoE.png -- So does the 2nd one: http://i.stack.imgur.com/BBeRX.png

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for something like `Simplify[Minimize[{If[x > 0, 3 x, x^2 - x - a], 1 < a < 2}, x], 1 < a < 2]`?

Comment: Thank you Michael, maybe the problem is that i have an older version? I got this : "10.1.0  for Linux x86 (64-bit) (March 24, 2015)"

Comment: What do you get for output? (It might help to give the output and version details in the question.) I can't try V10.1, but maybe use `PiecewiseExpand@If[x > 0, 3 x, x^2 - x - a]` for your function.

Comment: Also using PiecewiseExpand mathematica does nothing :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In versions before M11, maybe you can try something like the following:

```
minimize[{If[pred_, true_, false_], cond_}, x_] := Simplify[
    Min[
        First @ Minimize[{true, pred&&cond},x],
        First @ Minimize[{false, !pred&&cond},x]
    ],
    cond
]
```

The function needs error checking to be robust, but it works fine for your example (in M10.0):

```
minimize[{If[x > 0, 3 x, x^2 - x - a], -2 < a < 2}, x]
```

> Min[0, -a]

A more general version that works for [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise) expressions is also possible.

Comment: thank you so much! is working !!! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$Version

(* "10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014)" *)

Clear[f]

f[x_, a_] = PiecewiseExpand@If[x > 0, 3 x, x^2 - x - a]

(* Piecewise[{{3*x, x > 0}}, -a - x + x^2] *)

Plot3D[f[x, a], {x, -3, 3}, {a, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

```
Minimize[{f[x, a], -2 < a < 2}, {x, a}]

(* Minimize::wksol: Warning: there is no minimum in the region in which the 
objective function is defined and the constraints are satisfied; returning a 
result on the boundary. >>

{-2, {x -> 0, a -> 2}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! But this is not what I was looking for... I would like to find the minimum as a function of the parameter "a", while, as I understood, in your answer you consider "a" as another variable..

Answer (score 0):

Applying the minimization piecewise gives the expected result

```
Minimize[{3 x, x > 0}, x] (* {0, {x -> 0}}*)
Minimize[{x^2 - x - a, x <= 0}, x](*{-a, {x -> 0}} *)
```